# Flow Builder Fetch contacts

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

Trying to fetch the contacts created before 30 days, for those contacts send an welcome mail

[image: Screen Flow Component]
Any one can help?

T

[image: Formula resource]

[image: Get records component]

[image: Get records component]
[image: Debug Error]

Comment: Your text is not clear and comprehensive enough, sorry! Please revise. Consider screenshots of the whole flow and relevant flow element configurations.

Comment: Aside from the confusing variable name `Noofdayscount` (should be named to reflect a date), you are not finding any contacts because {!recordid} is NULL. Given this is a screen flow, the input variable should be named `{!recordId}` - capital `I`

Comment: After changing recordId also iam unable to fetch the records.

Comment: Can you help me with date formula to fetch records from last 30 days